# Dynamically Moving Through Hidden Tables With jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm having issues moving through a sequence of Hidden Divs that will eventually turn into Tables on another page that I am working on and the issue that I am running into is that the jQuery Javascript code does not seem to be responding to calls.

My JS Fiddle Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/qwertycody/QUprb/3/

My Actual Applied Work:

http://www.voyagersclan.com/scripts/pokemon/poke_pc.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
var currentID = 1;

$(function() {
        $('#left').on('click', function(){
        var currentDiv = '#' + currentID; 
        $('currentDiv').hide(500);
        currentID = currentID - 1;
        currentDiv = '#' + currentID;
        $('currentDiv').show(500);
    })
});

$(function() {
    $('#right').on('click', function(){
        var currentDiv = '#' + currentID; 
        $('currentDiv').hide(500);
        currentID = currentID + 1;
        currentDiv = '#' + currentID;
        $('currentDiv').show(500);
    })
});
</script>
```

Above is a code sample of my Javascript that doesn't seem to work correctly.

The overall goal of this is to be able to move through dynamically generated Tables with Individually Assigned Divs that can freely be Shown and Hidden at the press of a button.

Comment: it should be `$(currentDiv)` and not `$('currentDiv')`

Comment: Holy Crap. You are my hero. Thank you so much!

I've been staring at this screen for hours and I can't believe I forgot that.

Comment: It happens. you might forget the tiniest thing and keep looking for big mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is very close! The problem is that your selector is using a string, instead of the variable you intialized!

```
var currentDiv = '#' + currentID;
$(currentDiv).hide(500); // works!
$('currentDiv').hide(500); // gets an element of type "currentDiv"
```

Look at this [updated JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/cdRDT/2/)

I also added some bounds checks into your event handlers. This way you can only scroll through the available tables (1-4).

Comment: `$('currentDiv')` does not gets an element of type `currentDiv`. It gets the `currentDiv` tag

Comment: I do not see what you are saying here. Is this a discussion of terminology (tag vs element)? $(selector) will return the element, not the tag.

Comment: i mean to say you, it returns the element or tag `currentDiv` and not type of the element `currentDiv`.

Comment: It returns the element, not the tag. The tag would simply be the opening `<currentDiv>` tag. The element is `<currentDiv> ... </currentDiv>`. There is a difference. You are correct in that it returns the element, not the *type* of the element. I simply meant it will return an element of a specific type.

Comment: I think you need to know something.when it comes to Jquery the search item mentioned inside `$()` is an element.It can be tag name or id of a tag or name of the tag or something else. So when you specify simply `$('currentDiv')` it looks for the tag which an element in respect to Jquery.You could also read [here](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing :-)